# Proving there is a unique line m so that l ∩ m = P

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

In my geometry class I'm suppose to prove the following theorem.

Given line l and point P ∈ l, there is a unique line m so that
l ∩ m = P and the angles formed at the intersection are all right.

I was given the hint that I will need to prove two statements:
first that the line m exists, and secondly that m is unique. However, I'm confused how I would show that line m exists.

This is what I'm thinking....

Let A and B be distinct points, but are not on line L. Then by definition A and B create line m which is unique.

I don't really understand how I'n suppose to prove this, could someone please explain or show how I'm suppose to do this proof.

Comment: Suppose there were a second such line, then prove the angle between the two lines must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have $P \in m$, you have a point lying on the required line $m$

and since the angle between $m$ and $l$ is right angle you have the slope of the line $m$,

and since there is a unique line with a given slope and a point lying on it you can claim that the line $m$ is unique.